# Current user does not show up in form from ModelForm whilst relationship has been established in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have two models defined, a Test model and a User model. The Test model relates to the User model
with a ForeignKey. The Test model has many different aspects to it, so I have truncated it, but I make a form of it with ModelForm. Then I call the form, and indeed all the entries show up, including a cell for User, however it shows no options or pre-selection for current user. What am I doing wrong?

#User as rendered in form in browser:

```
<select name="researcher" id="id_researcher">
<option value="" selected>---------</option>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser)

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Return the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        return self.staff

    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        "Is the user a admin member?"
        return self.admin

class Test(models.Model):
    researcher = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="researcher")
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from database.forms import TestForm
from database.models import User, Test

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, "database/index.html")

def test(request):
    #If request is post, throw in data, check if valid, if correct, save it
    if request.method == "POST":
        form=TestForm(request.POST)
        print(form)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    
    context={"form": form}
    return render(request, "database/test.html", context)
```

test.html:

```
{% extends "database/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input type="submit">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

forms.py:

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from database.models import Test

class TestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Test
        fields='__all__'
```

Comment: Are you sure you registered a user? Did you set the `User` model as the `AUTH_USER_MODEL`?

Comment: Yes there are many users registered, and when logged in the user is also shown in the default index view. I tried to set the User in the ```AUTH_USER_MODEL```, but this resulted in many errors. I will try again!